# Improve speed of calculating a recursive sequence

Tags: c#

i'm trying to solve this proplem (below) with c#

> With a natural number, the following processes can be used:
>   Type 0 at the right of the given number
>   Type number 4 to the right of the given number
>   Divide the number to 2
>   If number 55 is given, can the following numbers be obtained: 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007
>   ((((( if we obtain number 32 then we can obtain any of this numbers: 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007 )))
>   We can find the solution with 28 steps.

So I wrote this code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    long number = 550, goal = 32;
    int count = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    find(number, goal, count, flag);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
 }
 static bool find(long number, long goal, int count, bool flag)
 {
     if(number==goal) { Console.WriteLine(number); return true; }
     if(count ==28 && number != goal) { return false;}
     else
     {
         flag =find(number*10, goal, count+1, flag); 
         if (flag == true) {  Console.WriteLine(number); return flag; }
         flag = find(number * 10 + 4, goal, count + 1, flag);
          if (flag == true) { Console.WriteLine(number); return flag;  }
         if (number % 2 == 0) {
            flag= find(number / 2, goal, count + 1, flag);
           if (flag == true) { Console.WriteLine(number); return flag; 
         } }
         return flag;
         }
       }
```

any one can speed the recursive progress up

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is straightforward, but naive. It will go through all possibilities until it finds a match. With a bit of thought, you can actually knock out a majority of the calculations.

When your recursive code executes, each recursive call separates into 3 paths, making it a maximum of **3^28** different possibilities. That is the worst case scenario, when the outcome of the method is false. Your code does resolve once the first path is found, but there is a good chance there will be a lot of time wasted on necessary calculations.

I am going to use your numbers as an example so I can be clear:

> Let's say I make the following call: find(550, 32, 0, false);
>
> At some point in time, your program will go down the path where it
>   will continually multiply 550 by 10. But why keep multiplying it by 10
>   if 32 is smaller than 550?
>
> At another point in time, your program will go down the path where it
>   will multiply 550 by 10 and add 4 continually. But like before, why
>   keep going up when the goal is smaller?
>
> So this is the final conclusion:
>
> Let **number** = The current value passed into the parameter, number.
>
> Let **remIteration** = The remaining number of recursive calls left. (28 - current recursive call #)
>
> Let **maxDivisor** = 2^x. This is the max value that the current value can divide by.
>
> Let **smallestFuture** = number / maxDivisor.
>
> Basically, **smallestFuture** is the smallest possible value from the
>   current recursive call. It is calculated by continually dividing the
>   current number by 2 until the recursive count reaches 28. Then, if
>   **smallestFuture** is still greater than the goal number, there would be
>   no point in computing the calculations down the current path.

Below is the code I've written. The function call was modified because I didn't think there was a point in using the flag parameter. Feel free to add it back in if you wish.

```
static bool find(long number, long goal, int count)
{
    if (number == goal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        return true;
    }

    if (count == 28 && number != goal)
        return false;

    int remIteration = 28 - count;
    long maxDivisor = (long)Math.Pow(2, remIteration);
    long smallestFuture = number / maxDivisor;

    if (smallestFuture > goal)
        return false;

    if (smallestFuture == goal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        return true;
    }

    long newNumber = number * 10;
    int nexCount = count + 1;

    if (find(newNumber, goal, nexCount) || find(newNumber + 4, goal, nexCount))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        return true;
    }

    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (find(number / 2, goal, nexCount))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough time right now to solve this problem using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), but it will definitely provide the better performance than my code. Do note that my code, much like yours, prints the first possible path it detects, not the most optimal.